# Outlook how to set a specific email for a specific receiver by default?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

The client am working with just gave me an email address on their server, and he want me to keep using it when i communicate with him, i successfully added this address to my outlook account, what i want now is that when i receive an email from someone with an @theCompany, when i choose to reply, i want that outlook automatically choose my new address (@theCompany) and not my original one.

If making detect the server automatically is impossible then it's okay to add the addresses one by one.

Thank you

Comment: i tried to look in the FAQ but didn't actually know what to search for so i posted here

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook 2013:

- Reply to the message.
- Under Options, click on From
- Select your other e-mail in the From dropdown

[image]

Comment: thank you but am talking about the web version, the one that is opened in the browser

Comment: Might help if you state that in your question...

Comment: sorry for that, also the last answer was completely wrong, someone told me this is how it's done and i thought that's correct, sorry